# Running NSTask inside a loop in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to run a simple shell command that runs and returns text rather quickly inside of a loop of indeterminate size at compile time that is generated by an NSArray.  In scripting languages like perl, I would be able to do something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<=$myinputarraysize;i++){
    $output[i]=`/my/task $inputarray[i]`;
}
```

This would build a new array for me from the expected output of my task.  In Obj-C this seems to be much more difficult and a bit confusing to me.  Right now my loop looks like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<[inputarray count]; i++){
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:nsdchat];

    NSArray *args;
    args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/my/task", [inputarray objectAtIndex:i], nil];
    [task setArguments:args];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput:pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *desc;
    desc = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
    desc = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

    [descriptions insertObject:desc atIndex:i];

    [task release];
    [args release];
    [pipe release];
    [file release];
    [data release]; 
}
```

My goal is to fill descriptions (an NSMutableArray) with the output from my task (which I know is always a string and always ends in a newline that I want to strip out).  It seems I'm missing something about memory releasing as when I run this and NSLog the output, I get the same result for the entire count of the loop.

Is there any easier or more way to loop through simple tasks like this?  Am I overcomplicating it for myself?

Comment: I'm confused - what's being printed to the log? This should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no need to do most of that work inside the loop. `task`, `pipe` and `file` all look like they could be handled outside the loop. You should also consider using Objective-C 2.0 dot syntax and fast enumeration to cut things down a little.

More significantly:

```
NSArray *args;
args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/my/task", [inputarray objectAtIndex:i], nil];
[task setArguments:args];
```

This says that the first argument passed to the executable at path `ndschat` is `/my/task`. Which doesn't seem to match your PERL usage. Probably you want just:

```
NSArray *args;
args = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[inputarray objectAtIndex:i]];
[task setArguments:args];
```

Or, with the style comments taken into account:

```
for(NSString *argument in inputarray)
{
    ...
    task.arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObject:argument];
    ...
}
```

EDIT: you're also releasing a lot of objects you don't own, which as well as adding heft to your code is a memory management error possibly leading to a crash. So, to cut the whole thing down and correct that fault:

```
for(NSString *argument in inputarray)
{
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];  // you now own this
    task.launchPath = nsdchat;

    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];          // you don't own this
    task.standardOutput = pipe;

    NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];  // you also don't own this

    task.arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObject:argument];
    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit]; // you should wait until the task is done

    NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];  // this is another thing
                                                // you don't own. Note also that
                                                // readDataToEndOfFile advances
                                                // the current read pointer, so
                                                // it should be fine to do this
                                                // successively 

    NSString *desc;
    desc = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                                                   autorelease];    
                                                // you don't own this because
                                                // of the autorelease; you
                                                // don't want to own it since
                                                // the next line will throw
                                                // it away


    desc = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
                                                // you don't own this

    [descriptions addObject:desc];
    [task release];
}
```

Comment: Still new to this, so excuse the dumb question, but do I not own NSPipe *pipe because it is owned by NSTask *task?  Object inheritance is still a little confusing.  I was releasing the objects trying to be able to reinstate them at the top of the loop, but it is clear to me now why this wrong (ownership).

Comment: Objective-C has a lot of conventions in place of formal language grammar, and constructors are one of them. The rule is that if the means you use to get hold of an object doesn't have any of the words 'new', 'alloc', 'retain' or 'create' (NARC is the nemonic) in it then you get a non-owning reference. If you don't own the reference then you don't need to `release` it. But Apple have added the ARC (automatic reference counting) compiler to recent versions of Xcode so that you don't actually need to think about this stuff any more if you don't want to.

Comment: Whoops; it's copy, not create. You get creates down in the Core Foundation stuff, which similarly mean 'an owning reference' in a sense, but C memory management (ie, no reference counting) is a whole other topic.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting a problem when trying to run my task inside of the loop with this syntax.  Everything compiles properly, but I am seeing "task already launched" when I try to NSLog my descriptions array.

Comment: In case anyone else is struggling to do the same thing, I stumbled across a small class called "ShellTask" that makes what I want to do incredibly easy.   You can download it here:  [link](http://vgable.com/blog/2008/03/05/calling-the-command-line-from-cocoa/comment-page-1/#comment-1363)

Comment: Oh! That's because I've been silly! You can't launch the same `NSTask` multiple times _simultaneously_. You probably need to move that stuff I moved outside the loop back inside or, I guess, you could set up a system to launch only one task at a time, though it'd be such a big change to your problem that it feels like a poor answer. I'll edit my answer above to do the former.